# Intersect does not fully process

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, intersection

Goal: Use python script to find overlap between various shapefiles in folders

Inputs: folder 1 with multiple shapefiles and folder two with multiple shapefiles

Method:

```
#First intersection
folder1_shp1 = "C:\..."
folder2_shp1 = "C:\..."
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(folder1_shp1 + ";" + folder2_shp1,OutputFolder + "/Intersection 1.shp","ALL","#","INPUT")

#Second intersection
folder1_shp2 = "C:\..."
folder2_shp2 = "C:\..."
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(folder1_shp2 + ";" + folder2_shp2,OutputFolder + "/Intersection 2.shp","ALL","#","INPUT")

#Third intersection
folder1_shp3 = "C:\..."
folder2_shp3 = "C:\..."
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(folder1_shp3 + ";" + folder2_shp3,OutputFolder + "/Intersection 3.shp","ALL","#","INPUT")

#Forth intersection
folder1_shp4 = "C:\..."
folder2_shp4 = "C:\..."
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(folder1_shp4 + ";" + folder2_shp4,OutputFolder + "/Intersection 4.shp","ALL","#","INPUT")
```

Problem: So you can see it's a pretty simple code, and it works. However, when I run it and I check the output shape files, some of the output files look like they haven't been fully processed.[image: Example output when it doesn't fully process] .

So I have to go back in and manually use the intersect tool on that particular intersection. [image: Example of the output when I manually intersect]

I use this code on many folders and there is no pattern as to which intersect won't fully process. It could be the first intersection, the second and the forth, all of them. The code doesn't throw an error and it proceeds to the next intersection where it may or may not fully process that one. I have tried rerunning the code (get different output scenario where some intersections processed more, some less) and adding in time breaks between intersections (no change). I have to do these intersections for hundreds of folders so checking each output and manually fixing them is pretty awful. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: how large are your output files?

Comment: 100 MB give or take

Comment: I was thinking you may have hit the shapefile size limit but you're still good, sorry.

Comment: Np, good thought

Comment: What happens when you examine just one of these "intersects that appears not to complete" in more detail and forget about all the others?  Does it "complete" when re-run on its own?  If you clip two inputs to a smaller area where the intersect appears no to "complete" does that part then "complete"?  At the moment I think you are only giving us the big picture rather than the detail necessary to make more sense of this so please [edit] your question to revise it.

Comment: If you have access to a machine with significantly more memory (perhaps 12GB instead of 4Gb) then it may be worth seeing if it will run there.  Particularly if you use the Task Manager to keep an eye on whether your failing process is approaching its quota.